# Convert multiple JSON objects to JSON Array and print it on file .json

Tags: java, arrays, json, redis

I have a json file with multiple json objects. This file is the result of a much larger file filtering and now I want to print a json array on file because this python loader (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/redis-dump-load/1.1) for Redis database doesn't allow multiple json objects. For example:

```
{"review_count":17,"stars":4.5,"business_id":"0DI8Dt2PJp07XkVvIElIcQ"}
{"review_count":9,"stars":5.0,"business_id":"LTlCaCGZE14GuaUXUGbamg"}
```

I want on physical json:

```
[{"review_count":17,"stars":4.5,"business_id":"0DI8Dt2PJp07XkVvIElIcQ"},
{"review_count":9,"stars":5.0,"business_id":"LTlCaCGZE14GuaUXUGbamg"}]
```

How can I do it in Java? I'm using json-simple library.

Comment: Are you limited to Java solutions only? If so, you probably should remove the python tag.

Comment: Somewhat off topic but relevant: you may want to look at ReJSON - a Redis module that does JSON - at http://rejson.io (disclaimer: author)

Comment: @ItamarHaber  I have some json file and I want to load them as (k,v) pairs,not in JSON format.

Comment: Create a JSONArray and read the json file, considering every line is a valid json object, parse it as JSONObject and add it to the JSONArray.